# TSQL Distinct does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I have the following query and I try to keep a unique value for each GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID using the DISTINCT keyword. Unfortunately I cannot make it work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CD.GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID, CD.DOWNLOAD_ID, PA.PHYSICAL_ASSET_ID
FROM 
    [CONTENT_DOWNLOAD] CD 
INNER JOIN 
    PHYSICAL_ASSET AS PA ON CD.GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID = PA.GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID
WHERE 
    CD.UPC = '00600753515501'
ORDER BY 
    CD.GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID
```

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` keyword will ensure that no duplicate *records* appear in your result set.  However, it makes no guarantee that a given column cannot have duplicate values across multiple records, if the combination of values in those records be distinct.

One option to get the distinct `GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID` values would be to use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CD.GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID
FROM [CONTENT_DOWNLOAD] CD 
INNER JOIN PHYSICAL_ASSET AS PA ON CD.GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID = PA.GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID
WHERE CD.UPC = '00600753515501'
ORDER BY CD.GLOBAL_CONTENT_ID
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know DISTINCT works on the combination of all the columns

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` works on every column in the `SELECT` clause, not just a single column. If one of those columns has a different value, then the row is considered different and returned as another row. In your query, you are including 'PHYSICAL_ASSET_ID' which has a different value for each row which is why you are getting multiple rows.